# Jaspersoft Studio - net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration

Tags: java, hibernate, jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

I am using the Data Adapter Wizard in Jaspersoft Studio 5.5.1 in order to set up a Hibernate connection.

The wizard asks for the Hibernate configuration (`hibernate.cfg.xml`) which is what I supply. My Hibernate configuration is functional in other settings...

When I test the connection in the wizard, I get the following error:

```java
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration
    at net.sf.jasperreports.data.hibernate.HibernateDataAdapterService.contributeParameters(HibernateDataAdapterService.java:137)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.data.AbstractDataAdapterService.test(AbstractDataAdapterService.java:129)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.data.wizard.AbstractDataAdapterWizard$3.run(AbstractDataAdapterWizard.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRClassLoader.loadClassForRealName(JRClassLoader.java:175)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.data.hibernate.HibernateDataAdapterService.contributeParameters(HibernateDataAdapterService.java:79)
    ... 3 more
```

It seems that the wizard is missing the Hibernate binaries. My question is; how to properly attach these binaries to the classpath of Jaspersoft Studio?

**EDIT**

One may add JARs to the classpath with 'The Database JDBC Connection' option:

[image]

But this isn't possible with the 'Hibernate Session' option:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seem that Jaspersoft studio classpath is located at:

`Jaspersoft Studio-5.5.1.final\features\jre.win32.win32.x86_64.feature_1.7.0.u25\jre\lib\ext`

When I copied Hibernate JARs to the classpath above, the exception I posted in my answer changed into:

```java
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at net.sf.jasperreports.data.hibernate.HibernateDataAdapterService.contributeParameters(HibernateDataAdapterService.java:147)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.data.AbstractDataAdapterService.test(AbstractDataAdapterService.java:129)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.data.wizard.AbstractDataAdapterWizard$3.run(AbstractDataAdapterWizard.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.data.hibernate.HibernateDataAdapterService.contributeParameters(HibernateDataAdapterService.java:121)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:245)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.loadDriverIfPossible(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:200)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildCreator(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1885)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1843)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1928)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:230)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:242)
    ... 22 more
```

The new exception is due to a missing SQL Server JDBC driver. So I copied this driver to the same classpath. The exception changed into:

```java
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at net.sf.jasperreports.data.hibernate.HibernateDataAdapterService.contributeParameters(HibernateDataAdapterService.java:147)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.data.AbstractDataAdapterService.test(AbstractDataAdapterService.java:129)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.data.wizard.AbstractDataAdapterWizard$3.run(AbstractDataAdapterWizard.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.data.hibernate.HibernateDataAdapterService.contributeParameters(HibernateDataAdapterService.java:121)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/ValidatorFactory
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.integrate(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:311)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1857)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1928)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.validation.ValidatorFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 16 more
```

This time the exception is due to a missing [Bean Validation API](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final). So I copied `validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar` to Jaspersoft classpath. This was ultimately enough to connect to Hibernate.

*Obs.* My Hibernate is 4.3.1.

Answer (score 2):

I worked my pom was added to this line

```
 <dependency>
<groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
<artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
<version>5.6.0</version>
<type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```